# While starting Selenium Server an error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null

Tags: selenium, server

I tried to start *Seleniun Standalone Server*. My steps were:

1. Downloaded selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar
2. Entered in cmd command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub`

## Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null
```

What should i do to start it without errors?

## Full log:

```
C:\>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub
12:37:57.401 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: 
'6fbf3ec767'
12:37:57.401 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2017-10-12 12:37:58.197:INFO::main: Logging initialized @975ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
12:37:58.211 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2017-10-12 12:37:58.258:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2017-10-12 12:37:58.286:INFO:osjs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-10-12 12:37:58.286:INFO:osjs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2017-10-12 12:37:58.289:INFO:osjs.session:main: Scavenging every 600000ms
2017-10-12 12:37:58.295:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1ad282e0{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-10-12 12:37:58.308:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@76ed93a3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-10-12 12:37:58.309:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1087ms
12:37:58.309 INFO - Nodes should register to http://192.168.56.1:4444/grid/register/
12:37:58.309 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
2017-10-12 12:41:32.842:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp989938643-13: /grid/register/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.process(RegistrationServlet.java:83)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.doGet(RegistrationServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is your `jdk` version you are using? Can you once try `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub -enablePassThrough false`

Comment: jdk version is 1.8.0_144. Parametr -enablePassThrough false doesn't help(

Answer (score 0):

When I try to browser "http://x.x.x.x:4444/grid/register/", got same log as you.
Try to browser "http://x.x.x.x:4444/grid/console/", the website is available.

So I think the Selenium Grid hub is up and running, we just visit the wrong address.